# Prevent Matplotlib to stretch plot to only bbox of drawing area

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

Please see below image:

[image]
I set the figure size of `plt` equal to something like `(4,6)` and set `axis` to `off` and `margin` to `zero`.
Then continue to draw polyline using coordinate array by `ax.plot(line[:,1],line[:,0])`

after this I don’t use the `plt.show()`
But convert the plot to numpy array which has correct (4,6) size but surprisingly fill the plot by stretched to only bbox of the draw line

How can i see all the unused space of figure?

Is there any flag that i have to change in somewhere in matplotlib?

Any help appreciated

Comment: Where is your code to discuss clearly? :)

Answer (score 0):

The plot of `matplotlib` will define the output based on `shape` and `size` of drawing not based on the pre-defined `figure size`,some kind of back-end and front-end, or simply it is a responsive-layout when you resize the window everything will scale else those are passed through `linewidth=` and ...

then i changed my workflow and problem solved ;)